# finding Bigrams in spark with java(8)

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-mllib

I have tokenized the sentences into word RDD. so now i need Bigrams.
ex. `This is my test => (This is), (is my), (my test)`
I have search thru and found `.sliding` operator for this purpose. But I'm not getting this option on my eclipse (may it is available for newer version of spark)
So what how can i make this happen w/o `.sliding`?

Adding code to get started-

```
public static void biGram (JavaRDD<String> in)
{
    JavaRDD<String> sentence = in.map(s -> s.toLowerCase());
    //get bigram from sentence w/o sliding - CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: Could you publish your code? Sliding only works on iteratble so you can use mapPartition with sliding. Once you upload the code I could write something up

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use n-gram transformation feature in spark.

```
public static void biGram (JavaRDD<String> in)
{
    //Converting string into row
    JavaRDD<Row> sentence = sentence.map(s -> RowFactory.create(s.toLowerCase()));

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())  
    });

    //Creating dataframe
    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sentence, schema);

    //Tokenizing sentence into words
    RegexTokenizer rt = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("split")
            .setMinTokenLength(4)
            .setPattern("\\s+");
    DataFrame rtDF = rt.transform(dataFrame);

    //Creating bigrams
    NGram bigram = new NGram().setInputCol(rt.getOutputCol()).setOutputCol("bigram").setN(2);  //Here setN(2) means bigram
    DataFrame bigramDF = bigram.transform(rtDF);


    System.out.println("Result :: "+bigramDF.select("bigram").collectAsList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sliding is indeed the way to go with ngrams. thing is, sliding works on iterators, just split your sentence and slide over the array. I am adding a Scala code.

```
val sentences:RDD[String] = in.map(s => s.toLowerCase())
val biGrams:RDD[Iterator[Array[String]]] = sentences.map(s => s.split(" ").sliding(2))
```